# Laravel filter results in query based on post

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the laraval model to query results from several tables. Now I do have this function:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $roles = Roles::withcount('permissions')
                  ->withcount('users')
                  ->orderBy('name')
                  ->get();

    return view('UserManagement::roles.overview', compact('roles'));
}
```

$request is filled with the filter I want to append. But how to set a filter including pagination as I can't append the Roles with ->paginate()

Maybe somebody can help me on this one?

Comment: you mean this?  $roles = Roles::withcount('permissions')
                  ->withcount('users')
                  ->where('fild_you_want_to_filter', $request->fild_you_want_to_filter)
                  ->orderBy('name')
                  ->paginate(10);

Comment: Yes, but the filter may not always being filled out. So the where query is working properly when it is filled out, but what if it is not being filled out at all

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Luis for pointing me to the right direction:

```
    $search = $request->has('search') ? $request->search : null;

    $roles = Roles::withcount('permissions')
                  ->withcount('users')
                  ->when($search, function ($query, $search) {
                      return $query->where('slug', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                  })
                  ->orderBy('name')
                  ->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [a conditional clause](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
$roles = Roles::withcount('permissions')
            ->withcount('users')
            ->when($request->field_you_want_to_filter, function ($query, $request) {
                return $query->where('field_you_want_to_filter', $request->field_you_want_to_filter);
            })
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: $roles = Roles::withcount('permissions')
                      ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                          if ($request->has('search'))
                          {
                              $query->where('slug', 'like', '%' . trim($request->search) . '%');
                          }
                      })
                      ->withcount('users')
                      ->orderBy('name')
                      ->paginate(20);

Comment: but is it allowed to do it this way?

Comment: Your solution is looking better, but I get this error:

ErrorException
Trying to get property 'search' of non-object

Comment: This is because the $request is empty form some reason.